# Как подключить отдельные стили для IE10+?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, style

Microsoft-то объявил, что теперь IE всё поддерживает, но по факту — c флексами беда, с бутстрапом — беда (по разному принимают отступы).

Как можно эти проблемы решить теперь, если условные комментарии отменили в версиях IE10+?

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил решение на чистом CSS. Скорей всего (в некоторых случаях), вам особые стили нужны будет только IE10. Особенно для flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот есть вариант с использоанием яваскрипт

javascript

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

css

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

[оригинал](https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/)

Comment: этот пример скорей всего для отдельных случаев, а если много чего править, то так код раздуется, наверное...

Comment: @ВладиславКураев Ваше, конечно, дело, но почему вы этот выбрали? Вам же вроде другой ответ подошёл...

Comment: ну этот ответ тоже даёт решение.

Answer (score 7):

Еще есть такой css хак:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   /* IE10 IE11 */
}
```

Если вам необходимо использовать его в сочетании с другими медиа-запросами, например, для организации адаптивной верстки, то можно объединять запросы. Например:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) and (max-width : 768px){
 /* IE10 IE11 до 768px по ширине*/
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51305/discussion-on-answer-by-mikl------ie10).

Answer (score 4):

#### Чистый CSS: условные стили для браузера (хаки)

Под `.selector` подразумевается нужный вам селектор.

```
/* Internet Explorer 11+ */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .selector { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Internet Explorer 10+ */
_:-ms-lang(x), .selector { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Internet Explorer 9+ */
_::selection, .selector { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Также можно так для IE10+ */
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  /* Нужные стили */
}
```

#### Отдельные файлы для каждого браузера и их подключение через JavaScript

Создаёте отдельный файл, к примеру, `ie.css`.

Далее подключаете его в зависимости от браузера.

1. Определяете является ли клиентский браузер IE. Также можете определять [версию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) и для неё давать специфические стили.
2. Если, да то создаёте элемент `link` и указываете ему `href` на наш файл `ie.css`.

Пример кода

```
var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;

if (isIE) {
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var link  = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel  = "stylesheet";
    link.href = "ie.css";
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* стили только для IE9 */ 
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
  button:active, button:focus {
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
  }
}

/* стили только для IE10 и IE11 */ 
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
  button:active, button:focus {
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
  }
}
```